# Distance mapping for a compact subset of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $A$ be a compact subset of a metric space $E$. Suppose $U$ is a
> neighbourhood of $A$; the real function $x\mapsto d(x,E-U)$ is $>0$
> ...

Why should $d(x,E-U)>0$ for each $x\in E$ (or is it for each $x\in A)$? For $x\in E$, by defintion:
$$d(x,E-U)=\inf_{y\in E-U}d(x,y)\geq 0.$$
How can I go from this definition to $0<d(x,E-U)$? (What happens if $U=E$?)

Comment: What do you mean by $E-U$? Is it the Minkowski difference or do you mean $E\setminus U$?

Comment: I mean the set difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author probably means $x\in A$ (or in the interior of $U$). It is universally true that $d(x,Y)=0$ if and only if $x\in\overline Y$.

Comment: Thank you. Usually, the uniformly continuous mapping, $x\mapsto d(x,B)$, where $B$ is a nonempty subset of a metric space $E$, is defined over $E$, right?

Comment: Yes, it is defined on the whole space and its zero set is the closure of $B$.